# how to "RESET" a jfx java application

Tags: java, javafx

How can I make the stage reset in JFX when I press the <kbd>R</kbd> key?

Something like:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.R){
        Platform.reset();
        event.consume();  }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by `RESET` ?

Comment: i mean like for all the elements on the stage to go back to the original launch state

Comment: so, does this code helps you?

Comment: Do you need to `RESET` the size of the stage ?

Comment: @seriallchiller Well as far as I know the platform "does not know" about app UI default state. So the easy way I guess - just relaunch application by pressing R. The solution I would prefer in your case is implementing 'State pattern'.